# Kendo Grid ASP.Net MVC server wrappers for local virtualization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

I was looking at the Kendo Grid local virtualization demo page and I noticed that the demo didn't include an example of an Asp.Net MVC server wrapper. Does that mean that there isn't one for the local virtualization mode of the grid?

Comment: You mean [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html)?

Comment: No that is the remote version of it. I was refering to the local version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that there isn't one for the local virtualization mode of the grid?

In the local version, as the name implies, there's no need for a server. The data is stored inside a javascript variable and lives only on the client. I don't understand what server side wrapper are you asking about. All you need is a server that will send the correct markup to the client. From this moment on everything happens locally.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was just thinking it would work similar to how the client side mode of the old MVC extensions grid worked. Where it uses a server wrapper to render the grid/set up everything initially

Comment: [This wrapper](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc) I would imagine.